# The meaning of "uniformly for"

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, inequality, terminology

What do the terms "uniformly for" and "according to multiplicity" mean? For the first term, it seems that it shouldn't mean simply (for the following result) that the formula holds for $x, T\ge 3$ such that we fix $x,T$ to be some numbers and any $y\in[X,3X]$, the formular holds. I guess it is about the error term $O\Big(f(X,T)\Big)$. It also seems to me to be different from "uniformly convergence" thing.

The second term, also seems confusing to me. Does it mean that $t\ge 0$ and $t<0$, for which $|t|\le T$, are counted as multiplicity, or what does it?

For $y\in [X,3X]$,
$$\psi(y)=y-\sum_{\rho}\dfrac{y^\rho}{\rho}+O\left(\dfrac{X\log^2 X}{T}\right)+O\left(\dfrac{X\log T}{T}\right)+O(\log X),$$
uniformly for $x, T \ge 3$. Here the summation extends over all non-trivial zeros $\rho = \sigma+it$ of $\zeta(s)$ counted according to multiplicity, for which $|t|\le T$.

Comment: I think you will need to give examples of these phrases used in sentences.

Comment: The "according to multiplicity" means that if $\zeta$ has repeated zeros, they appear in the sum multiple times.  For example, in the polynomial $f(x) = (x-1)^2$, $1$ is a zero of multiplicity $2$ so it would appear in the sum twice.

Comment: By the definition of $O$-notation, that assertion says that there exists a constant $C$ such that $$\biggl| \psi(y) - \biggl( y - \sum_\rho \frac{y^\rho}\rho \biggr) \biggr| \le C \biggl( \frac{X\log^2X}T + \frac{X\log T}T + \log x \biggr).$$ The phrase "uniformly for $x,T\ge3$" emphasizes that the constant $C$ does not depend on $x$ or $T$.